# Prove that $f(a)=\ell + \frac{(a-\ell)^{2}}{2}f''(c)$

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

Could you please help me to answer this question for freshmen students :

Let $f:I=[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $2$ and suppose that there exist $\ell\in I$ such that $f(\ell)=\ell$ and $f'(\ell)=0$. 
Without using Taylor-Lagrange theorem, prove that there exist $c\in]a,b[$ such that:

$$f(a)=\ell + \frac{(a-\ell)^{2}}{2}f''(c)$$

Noting that, we can use Rolle's theorem, mean value theorem, etc..

Comment: Yes, this is a Taylor polynomial... What is the question?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Without using Taylor-Lagrange

Comment: Immitate the proof of Taylor-Lagrange that uses just the mean value theorem.

Comment: could you please give me a reference for this proof